# Source file won't open after computer crash (c#, Visual Studio) ERROR CODE: 0x80041FEB

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I was working on a project on Visual Studio when my computer froze to the point I had to manually shut it down while having a .cs file unsaved.

When restarted, I got this error message when trying to open the .cs file: [Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwMgj.png)

I tried to open the file as a text file, but it seems empty.
Also a TMP file has been created in the project directory. This related .cs file is the only one that won't open. [Files in directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxf8d.png)

All I want is not to lose its content. If there would be just a way to get the code back somehow, it would be perfect.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Take a look in `%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\BackupFiles` - if it ain't there, you might have to start typing.. Did you ever run this project with a mostly-up-to-date file? The DLL/EXE in the bin/debug or bin/release folder might be able to be decompiled to retrieve the source (it may need some cleanup)

Comment: In Future use version control system or backup a folder.

Comment: There is no files in BackupFiles. I managed to decompile the EXE file as you recommended. There is quite some cleanup to do but it will do. Thanks a lot. Of course if someone has another idea I'll be glad to hear it.

Comment: You can try to report a problem on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=8).